# Can't seem to import pyqt_fit on spyder

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, spyder

I have been using Atom.io to run my python codes but recently I was not able to run codes that require pyqt_fit. I could not find any packages on Atom that allow me to run pyqt. As such, I downloaded anaconda and spyder. I used homebrew to intall qt, sip, and pyqt.

In spyder, I tried to do the following:

```
import pyqt_fit
from pyqt_fit import plot_fit
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab

x = np.arange(0,3,0.01)
y = 2*x + 4*x**2 + np.random.randn(*x.shape)
def fct(params, x):
    (a0, a1, a2) = params
    return a0 + a1*x + a2*x*x
fit = pyqt_fit.CurveFitting(x, y, (0,1,0), fct)
result = plot_fit.fit_evaluation(fit, x, y)
print(fit(x)) # Display the estimated values
plot_fit.plot1d(result)
pylab.show()
```

but I received the following errors:

```
runfile('/Users/Griffin/Atom/FYP Bifurcations/untitled1.py', wdir='/Users/Griffin/Atom/FYP Bifurcations')
Reloaded modules: pyqt_fit.utils, pyqt_fit.compat
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-24-effdfa66efe9>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/Griffin/Atom/FYP Bifurcations/untitled1.py', wdir='/Users/Griffin/Atom/FYP Bifurcations')

  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 93, in execfile
builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/Griffin/Atom/FYP Bifurcations/untitled1.py", line 9, in <module>
import pyqt_fit

  File "pyqt_fit/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from . import functions, residuals

  File "pyqt_fit/functions/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from .. import loader

  File "pyqt_fit/loader.py", line 3, in <module>
from path import path

ImportError: cannot import name path
```

Does it have anything to do with where I place the pyqt_fit folders? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PyQt-Fit requirements file](https://github.com/sergeyfarin/pyqt-fit/blob/master/requirements.txt), the [path.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/path.py/10.5) package is a dependency. However, the [PyQt-Fit package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt-Fit) has not been updated since 2015-02-11, and there have been incompatible changes made to `path.py` which it has not tracked. The specific error in the question is caused by [this change](https://github.com/jaraco/path.py/commit/62ccb7623d4d048af663f205e21c2ec3f24fa17d), which removed `path` as an alias for the `Path` class.

To fix this, you could try monkey-patching `path.py` like this:

```
# before pyqt_fit is first imported
import path
path.path = path.Path

import pyqt_fit
from pyqt_fit import plot_fit
```

Alternatively, you could downgrade `path.py` to any version >= 2.4 and < 8.0.

Comment: hi ekhumoro, thanks for your help! 

Apparently, pyqt worked for me after I removed all of the pyqt files in the anaconda and atom folders, and basically all traces of it on my laptop. I then reinstalled pyqt5 and saved it in the anaconda -> pkgs.

My guess is that I accidentally installed two versions of pyqt, namely pyqt4 and pyqt5, which led to some confusion probably.